# Nodejs 100% CPU usage, due to clock_gettime / gettimeofday / futex?

Tags: node.js

I'm dealing with a weird 100% CPU usage problem happening to a nodejs app. The app is quite large and I'm not sure where it's broken that caused this. The app is managed by pm2 in cluster_mode .

All I know is at the time of high CPU usage, `strace` outputs this:

```
root@a:/# strace -p 4350 -c
Process 4350 attached
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000031           0      3388           clock_gettime
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           read
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           write
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           rt_sigreturn
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000031                  3392           total

root@a:~# strace -p 3367 -r -c
Process 3367 attached
^CProcess 3367 detached
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 75.00    0.000939           0     91973           gettimeofday
 25.00    0.000313           0     39417           clock_gettime
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.001252                131390           total
```

The entire app is unresponsive at this point. After around 5 minutes, `pm2` will pick up and restart the process due to 'zero memory reported':

```
2016-12-03-20:29:05 PM2 [PM2][WORKER] Process 1 restarted because it uses 0 memory and has ONLINE status
2016-12-03-20:29:05 PM2 Stopping app:api-v2 id:1
2016-12-03-20:29:06 PM2 Process with pid 3367 still not killed, retrying...
2016-12-03-20:29:06 PM2 Process with pid 3367 still not killed, retrying...
2016-12-03-20:29:06 PM2 Process with pid 3367 still not killed, retrying...
2016-12-03-20:29:06 PM2 Process with pid 3367 still not killed, retrying...
2016-12-03-20:29:06 PM2 Process with pid 3367 still not killed, retrying...
2016-12-03-20:29:06 PM2 Process with pid 3367 still not killed, retrying...
2016-12-03-20:29:06 PM2 Process with pid 3367 still not killed, retrying...
2016-12-03-20:29:06 PM2 Process with pid 3367 still not killed, retrying...
2016-12-03-20:29:07 PM2 Process with pid 3367 still not killed, retrying...
2016-12-03-20:29:07 PM2 Process with pid 3367 still not killed, retrying...
2016-12-03-20:29:07 PM2 Process with pid 3367 still not killed, retrying...
2016-12-03-20:29:07 PM2 Process with pid 3367 still not killed, retrying...
2016-12-03-20:29:07 PM2 Process with pid 3367 still not killed, retrying...
2016-12-03-20:29:07 PM2 Process with pid 3367 still not killed, retrying...
2016-12-03-20:29:07 PM2 Process with pid 3367 still not killed, retrying...
2016-12-03-20:29:07 PM2 Process with pid 3367 still alive after 1600ms, sending it SIGKILL now...
2016-12-03-20:29:07 PM2 App name:api-v2 id:1 disconnected
2016-12-03-20:29:07 PM2 App [api-v2] with id [1] and pid [3367], exited with code [0] via signal [SIGKILL]
2016-12-03-20:29:07 PM2 Starting execution sequence in -cluster mode- for app name:api-v2 id:1
2016-12-03-20:29:07 PM2 App name:api-v2 id:1 online
```

Apparently this is caused by a pm2 bug: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2492 . But since if they had the bug fixed, it will not restart the process, thus leaving it stalled, I have no choice but to stick with older version now.

If I use `time` and `strace` to start the process, then:

```
real    0m45.765s
user    0m3.349s
sys 0m0.340s
www-data@a:~/$ strace -cf node /var/www/api-v2.js
Process 4020 attached
...
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 99.09    9.247853        4538      2038        26 futex
  0.18    0.016793           1     17777           clock_gettime
  0.16    0.015384          12      1262           epoll_wait
  0.11    0.010522         116        91           poll
  0.09    0.008339           2      5237      2437 stat
  0.08    0.007856           6      1234           write
  0.05    0.004309           3      1571           close
  0.03    0.003150           2      1790           read
  0.03    0.003150           2      1333       248 open
  0.03    0.003046          11       265           mmap
  0.02    0.002049           2      1186           lstat
  0.02    0.001617           4       378           madvise
  0.02    0.001535           2       917           fstat
  0.02    0.001518           1      1773           gettimeofday
  0.01    0.001096           1      1224        35 epoll_ctl
  0.01    0.000983           3       329        37 connect
  0.01    0.000792           1       667       329 accept4
  0.01    0.000734          10        76           brk
  0.01    0.000617           2       338           pread
  0.00    0.000315           2       155           socket
  0.00    0.000265           9        30           sendmmsg
  0.00    0.000184           1       144           munmap
  0.00    0.000162           1       113           mprotect
  0.00    0.000125           4        35           sendto
  0.00    0.000114           7        16           setsockopt
  0.00    0.000078           1        60           recvfrom
  0.00    0.000071           1       105           recvmsg
  0.00    0.000064           2        35           writev
  0.00    0.000052           7         8           clone
  0.00    0.000049           2        20        20 access
  0.00    0.000043           0       192           getsockname
  0.00    0.000029           7         4           getdents
  0.00    0.000024           1        36           bind
  0.00    0.000023          23         1           readlink
  0.00    0.000020           1        35           getsockopt
  0.00    0.000019          19         1           execve
  0.00    0.000018           0        86         9 ioctl
  0.00    0.000011           2         5           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000009           5         2           openat
  0.00    0.000006           1        11           getcwd
  0.00    0.000005           5         1           lseek
  0.00    0.000005           0        35           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000003           3         1           arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           listen
  0.00    0.000000           0        14           uname
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           getrlimit
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           getuid
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getgid
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           geteuid
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getegid
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           prctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           setrlimit
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_tid_address
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           clock_getres
  0.00    0.000000           0         9           set_robust_list
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           eventfd2
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           epoll_create1
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           dup3
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           pipe2
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    9.333037                 40661      3141 total
```

I don't have any `setTimeout` calls in my code, but I imagine I have dependencies that does. I have reviewed recent changes, and it doesn't appear to involve recursive calls or loops that never ends.

I have observed zero memory leaks, i.e. the pm2 memory size do not increase overtime. Previously the same program ran for 2 months without being restarted, at similar load. The server has more CPU, RAM, swap resources than necessary.

The problem started to appear after some routine maintenace on ubuntu (apt-get upgrade that upgraded nodejs, and mongodb, together with npm dependency upgrades). The nodejs upgrade went from 4.6.1 to 4.6.2. But when I downgraded back to 4.6.1, the problem is still there. I tried as far as 4.4.7 and 6.9.1, no version seem to work without problems.

How do I debug this problem? Where do I start?

Comment: Is it possible to log the incoming calls to build a simulation to get into that situation in a debugging environment?

Comment: are you running pm2 with watching file changes? I would disable that to see if that is causing the high CPU usage.

Comment: You need to narrow this down more. Does this happen only when particular bits of code are exercised? Can you reproduce it on a different physical machine?

Answer (score 2):

The debugging techniques in my question are incorrect. I'm doing such debugging only because Google results pointed me that way when you search for 'nodejs 100% cpu utilization'. And they turned out to be misleading.

The correct technique, is to let node itself to allow debugging via `node --debug=7000` for instance. At the point of high CPU utilization, run a debugging client `node debug localhost:7001`. And pause execution via `pause`. Try pause and run a few times, and you will be able to pinpoint the location of execution.

It turned out to be an infinite loop situation, i.e. `for (i=10; i>=0; i++)`.

I'm leaving the question and answer here in case someone else searches solution for similar behavior.